# Gocd pipelines (Config repo ) not triggering on changes

Tags: go-cd

I have configured gocd pipelines using config repo , But pipelines are not triggering on changes , we need to trigger pipeline maually at that time only pipelines are triggering , How can i make sure that pipelines should trigger on changes

Pipelines should trigger automatically on changes